# JMeter test with CAS not redirect to service

Tags: redirect, jmeter, cas

I am doing a jmeter test with CAS , but encountered a problem.

I got it logged in succesfully with full of CAS parameters(username/password/lt/service/_eventId), but the response data was  not my page specified in the parameter "service".

It is not redirected.

Why? Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: I am also using CAS in my JMeter Test. But I am unable to login because of service ticket issue. I used regular expression extractor. It did not work either. How did you do it? Could you please look into it and give feedback to me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465008/cas-ticket-issue-in-jmeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit that I am not so familiar with CAS...

After reading the protocol of CAS, I find this:
(from http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol)

2.2.4. response
One of the following responses MUST be provided by /login when it is operating as a credential acceptor.

successful login: redirect the client to the URL specified by the "service" parameter in a manner that will not cause the client's credentials to be forwarded to the service. This redirection MUST result in the client issuing a GET request to the service. The request MUST include a valid service ticket, passed as the HTTP request parameter, "ticket". See Appendix B for more information. If "service" was not specified, CAS MUST display a message notifying the client that it has successfully initiated a single sign-on session.

So ,I add a new request using GET with two parameters:service, ticket(its value is the same with lt).

Then the script run successfully and finally redirected..

Comment: You should accept your answer as the good one as it will help others.

Comment: I meet the same problem as you, but when I use your solution, it does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: @Bugdaily hi Bugdaily, I ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039199/how-to-test-cas-with-jmeter , need your help.