# Cas Ticket Issue in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing, cas, correlation

I have a web application which uses CAS Ticket for user authentication purpose which is different for every login. I recorded the script in JMeter. Also I correlated the pages by filling up the Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

[image]

Recorded script has url: `https://foo.com/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-3101-QDTyjbbHoOHvgPMdRBIg-cas`.

After applying all above I ran the script but got status fail displaying `https://foo.com/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=Ticket_Not_Found`.

It would be very helpful if someone could tell me what did I miss in my script?

Comment: try using http://rubular.com/ for regex testing..

Comment: Not sure how we can help you ? I mean how is it supposed to work ? What are you expecting ?

Comment: @HamZa The ticket needs to be dynamic so for every login Jmeter gets different ticket for authentication. So to make the ticket dynamic I used Regular Expression Extractor where Reference Name is given as "ticket". Now this reference name is used as a variable wherever the ticket will be used in the script. The regular expression field has a regex which will be used to create random ticket satisfying the standard format of cas ticket. After I re-run the script I want ticket=ST-3101-QDRyjffHoOHvgPMdRBIg-cas in request code.

Comment: @SuneetaSingh Ok, try with `ticket=(.+)` this will match until the end, so I hope there is no parameters after the ticket var :)

Comment: Did you make sure that the extractor works on the correct data? ("Response Field to check" == URL?)

Comment: @HamZa Tried with ticket=(.+) too. It did not work either. :(

Comment: @rsp Yes! I did check "Response Field to Check == URL". But I got same result for it when I ran the script.

Comment: You could try adding a DebugSampler to get JMeter variable values in the results tree and inspect the DebugSampler and HttpRequest information to see what the exact formats are (maybe the `=` is a `%3D` in the URL?)

Comment: @rsp = is not %3D in URL.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways for this,

if you have multiple username and password and you can use those with Jmeter,
you can use those to generate CAS ST(Service ticket).

Another:
default when CAS create ticket, it can be just used for one time.

you have to change  values in ticketExpirationPolicies.xml of your cas server
to use same ticket multiple times.

default location is:
WEB_INF/spring-configuration/ticketExpirationPolicies.xml

change this to if you want 50 users to use same ticket

```
    <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="1"
        value="100000" />
</bean>

<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.TimeoutExpirationPolicy">
    <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="0"
        value="7200000" />
</bean>
```

Answer given by: VIVEK ADHIKARI

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an error happened when fetching ticket value from url's parameter list. Maybe you can add a hidden field on your page and set its value from this parameter.
`<input type="hidden" id="ticket_key" value="ST-3101-QDTyjbbHoOHvgPMdRBIg-cas" />`
Then you can get it by Regular Extractor
 `ticket_key=(.+)`
Hope it helps.